# group_by relative date ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, group-by

I have a client who wants to see a report of her employees grouped by the date they took their last position (`date_in_position`). She wants them grouped by: Less than 1 year, 1-3 years, 3-5 years, and over 5 years. I made a little method to return a string usable for the `group_by` method, but only "less than 1 year" is working correctly. Everything else shows up as over 5 years.

```
def dip_range
  case self.date_in_position
    when 1.year.ago...Date.today
      '< 1 year'
    when 3.years.ago...(1.year.ago + 1)
      '1-3 years'
    when 5.years.ago...(3.years.ago + 1)
      '3-5 years'
    else 
      '> 5 years'
  end
end
```

Comment: Weird, when I run this I get a long loop of errors like: "warning: Time#succ is obsolete; use time + 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another way to approach it:

```
def dip_range
  case
    when self.date_in_position.between?(1.year.ago,Date.today)
      '< 1 year'
    when self.date_in_position.between?(3.years.ago,(1.year.ago + 1))
      '1-3 years'
    when self.date_in_position.between?(5.years.ago,(3.years.ago + 1))
      '3-5 years'
    else 
      '> 5 years'
  end
end
```

Comment: what is `case true`? Is it something new I don't know about?

Comment: no, just that between? returns true or false, so for the when to match the case statement, it needs to be true. It's a glorified if/else chain.  apparently, from other examples, the word true can be left out.

Comment: I believe for this particular case there is a `case when` form, explicit `true` is not required (Pickaxe 1.8, page 92)

Comment: I changed `case true` to just `case` ... although saying it explicitly doesn't hurt. :)

Answer (score 2):

In R1.8 (Time..Date) range doesn't work at all, besides I would rewrite this piece of code anyway:

```
# self is not required by the way
case (Date.today - date_in_position) / 365.2425 
when (0...1)
  '< 1 year'
when (1...3)
  '< 3 years'
when (3...5)
  '< 5 years'
else
  '> 5 year'
end
```

Or even:

```
years = (Date.today - date_in_position) / 365.2425
case  
when years < 1
  '< 1 year'
when years < 3
  '< 3 years'
when years < 5
  '< 5 years'
else
  '> 5 year'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer#years.ago` returns a `DateTime` which isn't comparing properly to the `Date` objects you are switching on. I'm not exactly sure why this is, but if you change

```
case self.date_in_position
```

to
    case self.date_in_position.to_datetime

this code will work for most cases.

Also, your bounds are incorrect.  If someone started work 1 year ago today, they should show as 1-3 years, right? So:

```
def dip_range
  case self.date_in_position
    when (1.year.ago+1.day).to_date..Date.today
      '< 1 year'
    when (3.years.ago+1.day).to_date..1.year.ago.to_date
      '1-3 years'
    when (5.years.ago.to_date+1.day).to_date..3.years.ago.to_date
      '3-5 years'
    else 
      '> 5 years'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want because it will match in order of priority, change the syntax if you like:

```
def dip_range
  t = self.date_in_position
  if t > 1.year.ago
    '< 1 year'
  elsif t > 3.years.ago
    '1-3 years'
  elsif t > 5.years.ago
    '3-5 years'
  else 
    '> 5 years'
  end
end
```